# How to charge this lead acid battery from child electric car?

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid

[image: Battery that I am trying to charge]

I don't have the charger that comes with it.
I tried hooking it up to  cheap 9v 500mA router transformer or something like that. 
[image: Charger hooked up]

But when putting in multi meter in the middle in serial connection, I don't see any  current flow...

Answer (score 4):

Please don't use a random charger to charge this battery. Spend the $8 and buy a purpose made lead-acid charger (like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001G8AIMU) one). Incorrectly charging this battery can be **dangerous**, just like it says on the side.

BUY A CHARGER. Look for one that is specifically for lead-acid, and specifically says "6 Volts". The one I linked to has a switch that allows you to choose between 6V and 12V. Obviously, you want to switch it to 6V. If you're not in the US, I can give you an amazon link for a charger you can get in your country, if you tell me what country.

edit: just to show what can happen when you [incorrectly charge these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27NQ8WNBUfo). This is a very severe, purposeful case of overcharging, but although these batteries are safer generally that Lithium cells, they are not immune to failure. When they do fail, they can send sulfuric acid and hydrogen spraying around.

Comment: I am in Canada (this one happens to ship there), I carefully read on the suggested charger, and there is one huge review from a guy called Paul, who says this: "If you measure the output with a digital multimeter, you'll measure the average value of the full-wave rectified voltage, at 11.5 V. But that's just the average value of a waveform that peaks at 17.4V. If you place a small capacitor across the output, you'll measure the peak voltage." - essentially suggesting high quality "switch-mode chargers" - But I cant find any... Can you please suggest a good quality one that wont destroy battry?

Comment: try https://www.amazon.ca/MICTUNING-Automatic-Electronic-Universal-Maintainer/dp/B01KXDNCNA

Comment: I looked at it, asked on the page to verify it works on 6V, I got conflicting answers.. 1 answer says it switches automatically (can it really know the type of battery on its own? how?) while another answer says only 12V...

Comment: That should be fine for 6V batteries. It is possible for it to switch automatically, because it can sense the voltage and current the is going into the battery and the charger. The answers on amazon are from random people (some of whom haven;t even bought the device), so are not always accurate. The manufacturer of the device says it's good for 6V, so I would believe that.